# How to add new Select2 option terms to the server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, jquery-select2

In a Rails 4 app I am using [Select 2 v4.0](https://select2.github.io/) to display a typeahead-style select field. Select2 generates the options from an ajax call to a json API within the app.

This is working great.

I now want to allow users to create a new item if their entry does not already exist in the json.

This is easy to set up on the client side

```
$('.my-field').select2
  tags: true
```

But what is the best way to handle this on the server?

My original thought was that, if an existing options is selected, the form would return an ID integer, whereas if a new item is selected, a string would be returned. I could then call a setter method in the controllers create method

```
def create
  @object = Object.build(params)
  if params[:my_field_id].respond_to?(:to_str)
    @object.setter_method = params[:my_field_id]
    params[:my_field_id] = nil
  end 
  ..
end
```

But of course even IDs are treated as strings in the params.

Next I thought I could modify the string so that new items can be distinquished. Select2 makes this relatively easy.

```
$('.my-field').select2
  tags: true
  createTag: (tag) ->
    {
      id: '<<<<' + tag.term + '>>>>'
      text: tag.term
     }
```

Then in the controller I could do something like

```
def create
  @object = Object.build(params)
  regex = my_regex_pattern
  if params[:my_field_id].gsub(regex)
    term = params[:my_field_id].slice('<<<<').slice('>>>>')
    @object.setter_method = term
    params[:my_field_id] = nil
  end 
  ...
end
```

So my questions:

1. Does this seem like a sensible approach, or am I overlooking a
   better way?
2. This approach seems like it could be quite brittle if, for example,
   the new item contains '<<<<'. Do I need to worry to about this?
3. My regex knowledge is poor to none. What is the best source of
   information to ensure that `my_regex_pattern` matches to `<<<<a
   random string of text>>>>`.
4. Are the `slice` methods the best way to remove these extra
   substrings?

EDIT

After a little playing, it appears that `slice` might be improved upon as follows:

```
term = params[:my_field_id].reverse.chomp('<<<<').reverse.chomp('>>>>')
```

It is a bit unwieldily and not the best readability. Is there a better way?